# JQuery - increment and identification

Tags: javascript

I only have notions of JQuery and again and that's why today I need help...

I am doing some kind of online editor to create my newsletters.
On this page: http://emaildesigner.fr/test/index.html and here the js: http://emaildesigner.fr/test/_scripts/newsletter-buildertest.js

The concept is classic: we click on "Add" -> header then + insert and this adds an editable block.
for the moment there is only one block but the concept is to put several and to use them once or several times each.

The blocks are constructed this way:

```
    <div class="sim-row" data-id="1">
      <div class="sim-row-header1">
      <div class="sim-row-header1-nav">
      <table width="700" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="hide" bordercolor="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#fff" style="background-color:#fff; border: 10px solid #ffffff;">
              <tr>
                <td class="sim-row-header1-nav-logo sim-row-edit sim-row-header1-slider-left-link" data-type="image"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;" class="sim-row-edit" data-type="link"><img src="http://static3.qcnscruise.com/images/newsletters/fr/2017-12-20-test/art/pdt01.jpg" alt="" width="700" /></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="height:10px;"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="sim-row-header1-slider-left-link"><a href="#" class="sim-row-edit" data-type="link" style="text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#555759; font:bold 20px arial; margin:0; text-align:left;" class="texte1">TEXTE</span></a></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<div class="ShowMobile" style="font-size:0;max-height:0;overflow:hidden;display:none; background-color:#FFF;">
 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="100%">
              <tr>
                <td><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;"><img src="http://static3.qcnscruise.com/images/newsletters/fr/2017-12-20-test/art/_pdt01.jpg" width="100%" border="0" style="display:block; background-color:#ffcecb; font:bold 14px arial; color:#000000; text-align:center;" alt="" /></a></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="height:10px;"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td class="sim-row-header1-slider-left-link"><a href="#" class="sim-row-edit" data-type="link" style="text-decoration:none;"><span style="color:#555759; font:bold 20px arial; margin:0; text-align:left;" class="texte1">TEXTE</span></a></td>
              </tr>
            </table></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

with the @media screen, I display either a mobile version or a PC version.

I need the publisher to update at the same time the PC code and mobile code (because the mobile code is hidden and it will do everything in duplicate ... since the resolution is too large).

in general, my blocks consist of 1 to 3 images, 1 to 6 texts and 1 to 3 links

I explain my problem to you :
currently when we click on "Add" -> header then + insert and this adds an editable block.
this block is composed of an image + link and a text + link
when I update the text (I put the code js only on the block text) it updates the part pc and the moving part but if I redo: "Add" -> header then + insert and well it me put the text of the block preceding what is logical.

```
$(document).on('keyup','#inputtexte1',function(){
    var txt = $(this).val();
    $('.texte1').text(txt);
});
```

So I think the solution would be to be able to identify each of the blocks and each of the parts to update in the same block and that the publisher only updates the mobile parts and pc of the block concerned (for the texts, the links, and images).

I can be found a beginning of track .... after still, it is necessary that I manage to adapt it ...

```js
var count=1;
$("#add").click(function(){
    var html="<div id='bloc"+count+"'><input type='text'></input></div>";
    $("#newBloc").append(html);

    count++;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="add">Add Addresses</button>
<div id="newBloc"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope to have been clear.
Can you help me?
Sorry for my bad English but I'm french

thank you in advance

Comment: your right. You must have to make **unique** Id by  increment for individual identified. 
But now what you face to do ?

Comment: thank you for reassuring me that I'm on the right track
can you help me to adapt the code?

Comment: can you add your code in [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/) Then I can edit and adapt your code .

Comment: @MD Ashik  https://jsfiddle.net/2soj08b8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ZeroCool I was try to help you and make a Example for your solution [Live link for example](https://codepen.io/ashikjs/full/BJxyyw/) I hop you get the concept for this issue.

Add a Parent Id and `onClick` get **parentId** Then `keyup` call bay this **parentId** with your `class` name. Like ..

After set a parent id ...

```
// Global veritable dicelear  
 let userId = '';

$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() { 
  userId = '#'+ $(this).closest('ul').attr('id') + ' .userName'; //use #parentId
  $('#edit-from').modal('show') // Open your edit from ...

});

 $( "#memberNameGet" ).keyup(function(){
    $(userId).text($(this).val());
 });
```

```js
let Id=1;
let userId = '';
$("#add").click(function(){
  let userName = $('#newUserName').val()
    let html='<ul id="user'+Id+'">'+
      '<li><span class="userName">'+userName+'</span>'+
      '<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-primary edit_user">Edit </a>'+
      '</ul> </li>';
    $("#newBloc").append(html);
    Id++;
  $('#newUserName').val('')
}); 
$(document).on('click', '.edit_user', function() { 
  userId = '#'+ $(this).closest('ul').attr('id') + ' .userName';
  $('#myModal').modal('show')
  // console.log(userId);
});
 $( "#memberNameGet" ).keyup(function(){
   // alert(userId);
    $(userId).text($(this).val());
 });
```

```css
span, a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right:15px;
}

input {
padding: 5px 15px }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



</br>
<div class="col-md-6">
  
<input type="text" id="newUserName">
<button id="add" class="btn btn-success"> Add Member</button>
</div>
</br></br>
<div class="col-md-5">
  <div id="newBloc"></div>
</div>


<!-- Add member modal -->


  <div class="modal fade " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Edit Member</h4>
      </div> 
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nameValue">Member Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="memberNameGet" placeholder="Type Member Name ">
            </div>
          </div>
         
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Updated</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: can you help me again please ?

Comment: @ZeroCool Yes but maybe I was busy with my exam :( but now you can share your problem ...